# Error whle trying to convert keras model to tf saved_model. - AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have to serve keras model in tensorflow serving. For that, I am trying to convert keras model to tf saved_model format using this script. https://gist.github.com/himanshurawlani/8a017b2a893060d1282d13ea4a8ddefc

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
import networks.generator as gen
import tensorflow as tf
K.set_learning_phase(0)

encoder = gen.encoder(3, 224)
encoder.load_weights(f"weights/encoder.h5")
encoder_path = 'model/encoder/1'

print(encoder.outputs)

with tf.keras.backend.get_session() as sess:
tf.saved_model.simple_save(
    sess,
    encoder_path,
    inputs = {'input_image': encoder.input},
    outputs = {t.name: t for t in encoder.outputs}
)
```

But I am getting *`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'`* in `---> 18         outputs = {t.name: t for t in encoder.outputs}`

Output of `print(encoder.outputs)`:

```
[<tf.Tensor 'activation_4/Relu:0' shape=(?, 14, 14, 512) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'lambda_5/resize/ResizeBilinear:0' shape=(?, 112, 112, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'lambda_6/resize/ResizeBilinear:0' shape=(?, 56, 56, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'input_3:0' shape=(?, 224, 224, 3) dtype=float32>]
```

**For reproducing errors-**

Network module - https://github.com/shaoanlu/fewshot-face-translation-GAN/tree/master/networks
Encoder Weights - https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1DUMmZGTGKMyEYSKy-w34IDHawVF24rIs

Comment: I want to serve model using tf serving and for that I need saved_model. And I can't see anywhere saved_model being deprecated.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `saved_model.simple_save()` is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

The example you tried to follow, has an issue. As we can read in the `tf.compat.v1.saved_model.simple_save` [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/saved_model/simple_save):

> `outputs:` dict mapping string output names to tensors. These are added
>   to the SignatureDef as the outputs.

So you tried to pass a dict value as a generator object, which has been converted a list:

```
[<tf.Tensor 'activation_4/Relu:0' shape=(?, 14, 14, 512) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'lambda_5/resize/ResizeBilinear:0' shape=(?, 112, 112, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'lambda_6/resize/ResizeBilinear:0' shape=(?, 56, 56, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'input_3:0' shape=(?, 224, 224, 3) dtype=float32>]
```

to `outputs` parameter, which expects a tensor.

An simplified example to a generator object you tried to pass:

```
print(type(x for x in [1,2,3]))
```

**out:**

```
<class 'generator'>
```

Comment: No. I passed dictionary - {t.name: t for t in encoder.outputs}. I only printed list.

Comment: @DeepakMangla I make an edit in my answer, actually you pass a generator object

Comment: @DeepakMangla If you provided a reproducible code snippet with play data, the I can give you a solution.

Comment: You should rather run - 

`print(type({a: a for a in range(10)}))` 

**out**

<class 'dict'>

I have also provided sources in my question for reproducing errors.

Comment: @DeepakMangla I am getting similar issue when I try to save keras model in TFS. Have you got any solution for this ?